# iOS Regular Expression to check whether a NSString starts with g

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am new to Regular Expressions and its usage in iOS .I have a scenario where I have to check whether a `NSString` starts with 'G' this is my function which returns the bool condition . I am passing the data like this

```
[self compareStringWithRegex:@"Gmail" withRegexPattern:@".*g"];

-(BOOL) compareStringWithRegex:(NSString *) string withRegexPattern:(NSString *)expression
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];



 NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (match){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, this function returns true if I give wrong condition . Please help me in this and let me know if my question is not clear .

Comment: "Regular Expression to check whether a NSString starts with g" – **nope, nope, *nope!*** You don't need (therefore you *shouldn't* use) a regular expression for that. Use NSString's `hasPrefix:` method instead.

Comment: no we are allowing users to use regular expressions . so it depends on the user he can even give .* condition

Comment: you seem to be confusing two scenarios. *Either* you want to check statically whether a string starts with the letter G *xor* you want someone to input an arbitrary regular expression and match it with a string. You asked about the former scenario, not the latter. Why are you complaining when you get an answer about what you asked and not about some arbitrarily wide superset of that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Regular Expressions to check string start with "g" then
replace ".*g" with "^g" it will give you asspected result

```
 [self compareStringWithRegex:@"Gmail" withRegexPattern:@"^g"];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response . But the first condition (.*g) it should return false right ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use regex the `@"(g)+(\\w+)"` should work. I tested it on [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/)